# session_start in php in index.php

Tags: php, session

On my index.php, I have a login form. The form has a method of POST and its action is sent to a authentication file i.e action="authenticate.php". In this authentication file I check to make sure the user exists, I start a session, and then I redirect back to index.php.

Because I want the index.php content to change, for example, there will be no login form but the user account information, I also place a session_start() at the top of my index.php...

The problem occurs when a user visits my page for the first time. Because I placed a session_start() at the beginning of my index.php, if the user leaves and decides not to log in, then I'm stuck with an empty session file which takes up space on the server.

Is this bad practice? Is there another method that I should use? I hope this makes sense.

Comment: It's best to use `if(isset($_SESSION['session_name'])){...}` in order to check if the session is set. If so, then let it do something; or not.

Comment: How much space do you think an empty session takes up? Unless your server is a 286, I don't see the problem.  This isn't the 90s anymore; servers should have enough RAM to handle it.

Comment: @developerwjk Even an XT lol a 286 was a blazer compared to those. I had both myself.

Comment: You need to disconnect your association of a PHP session from a logged user application session.  They are not one and the same.  Most session-aware applications start up PHP sessions on all page requests without regards to any user login status or other application-level construct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP cleans up sessions that are not in use anymore.

The usual configuration is to only run cleanups on a percentage of requests, and then to clean up session files that haven't been used in the last 30 minutes. Note that this leaves an opportunity for sessions to live longer on sites that rarely have any requests, so it is best practice to record the enforced logout time inside the session itself if there is a need to log the user out when being inactive after for example 15 minutes.

Also note that on a badly configured shared hosting you might gain access to other sites session files and vice versa, which might also affect cleanup of session files if other sites have a different, shorter timed configuration.

But all in all PHP takes care of the sessions itself pretty well.